# "Enter" key behavior

Tags: support

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I keep accidentally posting answers or comments by hitting the Enter key to insert a paragraph break.  I'm finding myself writing text in an external editor and pasting to prevent this problem.  Is there a description of the text editor behavior somewhere so I can learn how it works?  I'm using Firefox 5.0 if it matters.

Comment: Firefox *5.0*???

Comment: Apparently they went from 4.0 to 5.0 after only a few months.  It was an auto-update recently.  To be honest it was so unexpected I thought I had a virus for a few minutes.

Comment: I see. I'm still on 3.6.18, so I missed that. (When I tried 4.0  on my XP laptop it crashed with a BSoD. Besides, I have add-ons which aren't 4.0 compatible (let alone 5.0) :-( )

Comment: @stevenvh They decided to get rid of smaller version numbers and instead keep increasing the major number. For example, 7.0 is now in development and 6.0 is in beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has been reported before, for example [here on meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form).  Please don't respond like [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/threatening-emails-from-jeff-atwood); instead, if it really bothers you, then add [this script to your browser](https://stackapps.com/questions/2061/disable-enter-for-submitting-comments).

Comments are designed to be more like a chat session: The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key submits the comment.   If you've never used a chat client, this may take some getting used to, but now you know.

There is no way to insert a permanent line break (temporary ones entered with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd> are stripped before submission), so the use of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for this purpose isn't usually a problem.  All multi-line fields on the site automatically word-wrap, so you don't need to terminate your lines yourself to 80 characters.

If you make a mistake, you can edit your comment up to three times.  Hover over it to get the edit button shown below:

[image: picture of comment with edit button]

Jeff explained the behavior on SO [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments/33939#33939):

> You can now edit your own comments after you post them, within a 5 minute window.
>
> How do you know a comment has been edited? A little pencil icon will appear next to it. The mouseover title tooltip explains what this pencil icon means, and also provides a count of how many times the comment was edited in that 5 minute window.
>
> Moderators can edit any comments at any time. This action is logged and visible in that moderator's user history to other moderators.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the big UI problem is that the text boxes for answers and comments don't act the same even though they look the same.  It didn't occur to me that line breaks weren't permitted in comments until I tried on purpose to edit one in and failed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question directly, but I have occasionally been caught by hitting ENTER and having it close and post the comment.  Fortunately you can fix that.  You have a small window of time where you can edit your own comment before it becomes frozen.  I forget exactly how it works, but I think you hover over the start or the end of the comment and a edit option appears.  Or may it always appears during the edit grace period, I don't remember.

In any case, I know this works because I've done it.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've done a few times, or even deleted the comment and started over.  So far nobody's tried to reply to a half-finished comment before I reposted it.

Comment: @Olin, @Matt - I think a comment can be edited for 5 minutes after posting.

Comment: I also think, as it was this way when I last was not a mod but may have changed, that you can always delete your comment and type a new one. Often an easy solution as you can copy paste what you have already written in moments. @stevenvh, if you @ more then one person I believe it only notifies one person but you should not need to @ olin as it always notifies the post owner, or should.

Comment: @Kortuk - Ok, thanks for the tip. Yes, you can always delete a comment and add an edited version, but it has caused confusion before when I deleted a comment exactly at the moment somebody replied to it. So the result was that the reply came before the comment. :-/

Comment: @stevenvh, hopefully you catch it within a minute of your error. There is no perfect answer except to remember that comments are noise on top of answers which form the true signal. They are there to discuss and improve the answer (and bicker).